# How to override Sizzle()

Tags: javascript, jquery, sizzle

**Having problem overriding Sizzle()**

We encountered "SCRIPT70: Permission denied" exception in IE apparently, our fix is to hack our current version of jquery however we dont want to modify original Sizzle()

```js
(function ($) {

    $.fn.Sizzle = function (selector, context, results, seed) {
    var match, elem, m, nodeType,
        // QSA vars
        i, groups, old, nid, newContext, newSelector;

    // This try/catch seems to fix IE 'permission denied' errors as described here:
    // http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/14535
    try {
        document === document; //may cause permission denied
    }
    catch (err) {
        document = window.document; //resets document, and no more permission denied errors.
    }

    if ((context ? context.ownerDocument || context : preferredDoc) !== document) {
        setDocument(context);
    }

    context = context || document;
    results = results || [];

    if (!selector || typeof selector !== "string") {
        return results;
    }

    if ((nodeType = context.nodeType) !== 1 && nodeType !== 9) {
        return [];
    }

    if (!documentIsXML && !seed) {

        // Shortcuts
        if ((match = rquickExpr.exec(selector))) {
            // Speed-up: Sizzle("#ID")
            if ((m = match[1])) {
                if (nodeType === 9) {
                    elem = context.getElementById(m);
                    // Check parentNode to catch when Blackberry 4.6 returns
                    // nodes that are no longer in the document #6963
                    if (elem && elem.parentNode) {
                        // Handle the case where IE, Opera, and Webkit return items
                        // by name instead of ID
                        if (elem.id === m) {
                            results.push(elem);
                            return results;
                        }
                    } else {
                        return results;
                    }
                } else {
                    // Context is not a document
                    if (context.ownerDocument && (elem = context.ownerDocument.getElementById(m)) &&
                        contains(context, elem) && elem.id === m) {
                        results.push(elem);
                        return results;
                    }
                }

                // Speed-up: Sizzle("TAG")
            } else if (match[2]) {
                push.apply(results, slice.call(context.getElementsByTagName(selector), 0));
                return results;

                // Speed-up: Sizzle(".CLASS")
            } else if ((m = match[3]) && support.getByClassName && context.getElementsByClassName) {
                push.apply(results, slice.call(context.getElementsByClassName(m), 0));
                return results;
            }
        }

        // QSA path
        if (support.qsa && !rbuggyQSA.test(selector)) {
            old = true;
            nid = expando;
            newContext = context;
            newSelector = nodeType === 9 && selector;

            // qSA works strangely on Element-rooted queries
            // We can work around this by specifying an extra ID on the root
            // and working up from there (Thanks to Andrew Dupont for the technique)
            // IE 8 doesn't work on object elements
            if (nodeType === 1 && context.nodeName.toLowerCase() !== "object") {
                groups = tokenize(selector);

                if ((old = context.getAttribute("id"))) {
                    nid = old.replace(rescape, "\\$&");
                } else {
                    context.setAttribute("id", nid);
                }
                nid = "[id='" + nid + "'] ";

                i = groups.length;
                while (i--) {
                    groups[i] = nid + toSelector(groups[i]);
                }
                newContext = rsibling.test(selector) && context.parentNode || context;
                newSelector = groups.join(",");
            }

            if (newSelector) {
                try {
                    push.apply(results, slice.call(newContext.querySelectorAll(
                        newSelector
                    ), 0));
                    return results;
                } catch (qsaError) {
                } finally {
                    if (!old) {
                        context.removeAttribute("id");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // All others
    return select(selector.replace(rtrim, "$1"), context, results, seed);
};
}(jQuery));
```

Ref: https://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/14535
https://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/14535#comment:11

Comment: Did you manage to override it successfully?